# "the National Park Service’s Southeast Coast Network Climate Science Support Center" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

I ran into this:

> the National Park Service’s Southeast Coast Network Climate Science Support Center

It seems odd because it has too many noun modifiers. I understand this as:

**The Center which Supports Climate Science (Climatology) in the area of Southeast Coast Network, which is (and this Center is) a part of the organization National Park Service**.

Am I right?

Comment: Please remember to include [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like a source or link to the original material.

Comment: @Max I saw this in an email, there were no more details unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently the **Support Center** for **Climate Science** affiliated with the **Southeast Coast Network**, owned by the **National Park Service**, which presumably has several such **Networks**.

So - I think your understanding is correct.

Comment: You mean *Southeast Coast Network* is an organization? I felt it is talking about a geographic concept.

Comment: @Juya It is definitely ambiguous there, but their page [here](http://science.nature.nps.gov/im/units/secn/) suggests that it is indeed an organization.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Thanky you. I checked it,*The Southeast Coast I&M Network is one of 32 National Park Service I&M Networks across the country established to facilitate collaboration, information sharing, and economies of scale in natural resource monitoring.*, and I think it is a geographic concept.

Comment: +1 At any rate, there's no such thing as "network climate".